# puppeteer goto method not in camelcase?

Tags: puppeteer, camelcasing

What is the reasoning for puppeteer's `goto` method not being *lower camel case*, e.g. `goTo()`, as every other puppeteer method is?

Ironically, searching `goto` as one word on google brings up results that define it in a programming context, but more so in the context of jumping to the next line, as in a debugger, not in the context of navigation to a page.

I get that this question pertains to *coding styling* and may result in opinions, but it seems to me that writing every api method in camelcase besides *one* is either bad form (opinion, I guess) or I am missing something about camel-casing/formatting that could serve me in the future.

Comment: This is not the question to the SO community, but specific to developers of the package. As of, has to be addressed directly at [https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues).

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Sure, possibly. I did think of that. But I also don't necessarily consider this an "issue", as there may be a more industry-wide reasoning for it, and I don't feel the issues thread of github is the place for a simple curiosity (but maybe it is).

Answer (score 0):

Might be historical reasons as `goto` comes from many earlier programming languages (e.g. MS/DOS shell scripts), where it was used as a single word and established itself over time as one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto

I am inclined to name my functions like `gotoNextStep` in my code because of those reasons. I.e. past experience and established terms. It just clicks in. Developers, that I work with who entered the profession later and who are less familiar with `goto` as a practical command, tend to use `goToNextStep` notation following the general casing pattern.